# instaling matplotlib for python 2.7 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have to run some all programs written in python2.7. They use library "matplotlib". In the repository of Ubuntu 20.04 there is no candidate for installing it and matplotlib for python3 is not compatible with the programs I'm trying to run.
Is there a way to install matplotlib for python2.7 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Without a specific package name, you are asking us to guess. The `python-matplotlib` package, compatible with Python2, was removed from the Ubuntu repositories after 18.04. You can download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com. Or you can use pip.

Answer (score 1):

To install [python-matplotlib](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-matplotlib) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you have to download packages from 18.04 LTS with commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-cycler/python-cycler_0.10.0-1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/matplotlib/python-matplotlib_2.1.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-matplotlib_2.1.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./python-cycler_0.10.0-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Although it works, it says: `Bad key "lines.markeredgecolor" on line 12 in /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/classic.mplstyle. You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template or from the matplotlib source distribution
Bad key "lines.markerfacecolor" on line 11 in /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/classic.mplstyle. You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template or from the matplotlib source distribution`